# ¿Cómo ejecutar 2 eventos diferentes con un click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quisiera saber como puedo ejecutar dos códigos diferentes en JavaScript con un evento "click". Por ejemplo:

Primero quiero que se ejecute este código cuando presiono click:

```
let footer1 = document.getElementById("Infooter");

footer1.addEventListener("click", function(){
let footer3 = document.getElementById("Infooter3");
let origfooter = document.getElementById("footer");

origfooter.style.height = "50%";
footer2.style.top = "60%";
});
```

Después quiero presionar nuevamente click y que se ejecute este código:

```
footer1.addEventListener("click", function(){
let footer3 = document.getElementById("Infooter3");
let origfooter = document.getElementById("footer");

origfooter.style.height = "25%";
footer2.style.top = "25%";
});
```

Comment: Puedes usar tanto el click como el dblclick. Revisa esto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Comment: Puedes compartir tu código html? Creo que tengo una respuesta para tu pregunta pero necesitaría ver tu html.

Comment: En el primer evento click eliminas ese listener y le pones el  listener al click con la función del segundo y el el segundo quitas nuevamente el listener y le pones el del primero.

Comment: O simplemente tienes solo el evento click y dentro del evento click preguntas si tiene la clase Dos si no la tiene entonces ejecutas el primer bloque y le agregas lel clases Dos. En el segundo click como ya existe el clases Dos ejecutas el segundo bloque y eliminas el class Dos. También puedes aprovechar en poner en los class el estilo que desea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es que cada vez que se hace clic vaya del primer código al segundo y luego regrese al primero, puedes tener un único evento y hacer *toogle*, para ejecutar un código u otro con una variable de control, que vas aumentando y luego, dependiendo de si es par o impar, aplicas un tamaño o el otro, por ejemplo:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
div{
    height: 10%;
}

#Infooter3  {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10%;
}

#footer {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 15%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Infooter">¡haz clic aquí!</div>
  <div id="Infooter3">f3</div>
  <div id="footer">f</div>
</body>
<script>
  let dvInfooter = document.getElementById("Infooter");
  let control=-1;
  dvInfooter.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let origfooter = document.getElementById("footer");
    control += 1;
    if (control%2==0) {
      origfooter.style.height = "50%";
    } else {
      origfooter.style.height = "25%";
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el evento de doble click (dblclik) El Código te quedaría así:

```
let footer1 = document.getElementById("Infooter");

let footer3 = document.getElementById("Infooter3");
let origfooter = document.getElementById("footer");

footer1.addEventListener("click", function(e){

origfooter.style.height = "50%";
footer2.style.top = "60%";
});

footer1.addEventListener("dblclick", function(e){

origfooter.style.height = "25%";
footer2.style.top = "25%";
});
```

Comment: Te sirvió la respuesta? Recuerda marcar como respuesta esperada si te sirvió, no solo por mi, sino también para que otros que consulten la pregunta puedan beneficiarse también?

Answer (score 1):

podes hacer un ternario que tome el valor actual y lo cambie por el que corresponda, esto también fuerza el valor inicial de 25%.

```
let footer1 = document.getElementById("Infooter");

footer1.addEventListener("click", () =>{

    let Infooter3 = document.getElementById("Infooter3");
    let footer = document.getElementById("footer");

    Infooter3.style.height = Infooter3.style.height=="25%"?"50%":"25%"
    footer.style.height    = footer.style.height   =="25%"?"60%":"25%"

});
```

También podrías agregar o quitar una Class en la etiqueta html con una clase

```
Infooter3.classList.toggle("mystyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo como esto:
Nota: En lo personal me gusta tener mis referencias a elementos HTML a todo el inicio de mi archivo .js, esa sección de @elements la puedes ignorar

```
// @elements
const elFooter = document.getElementById('Infooter');
const elFooter2 = document.getElementById('Infooter2');

// flags
let dispatchFunction1 = true;

// @actions
const function1 = () => {
    elFooter.style.height = '50%';
    footer2.style.top = '60%';
};

const function2 = () => {
    elFooter.style.height = '25%';
    footer2.style.top = '25%';
}    

elFooter.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (dispatchFunction1) {
        function1();
    } else {
        function2();
    }

    dispatchFunction1 = !dispatchFunction1;
});
```